# Function.apply() is throwing error in release mode in android

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have a dynamic function call that works great in web and iOS. But in android alone it throws the below error.

Im calling the function as like
`params = Function.apply(params.copyWith, [], map);`

Even in Android, it is working fine in debug mode, and release mode. But throws error only after taking apk / aab build.

`NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function ‘xC.kfc’`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that can reproduce the problem?